# Rails Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

There's something wrong with my heroku setup and I'm trying to fix it with

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get the error message

```
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```

How do I fix this?

I have set my heroku environment variables. `heroku config` gives

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:           XXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:       XXXXX
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://XXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:XXXXX
RESQL_BLACK_URL:             postgres://XXXXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:XXXXX                    
LANG:                        en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                    production
RAILS_ENV:                   production
S3_ACCESS_KEY:               XXXXX
S3_BUCKET:                   XXXXX
S3_SECRET_KEY:               XXXXX
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:           XXXXX
SENDGRID_USERNAME:           XXXXX
```

Do I need to add something to config/production.rb? I tried this:

```
config.aws_access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
config.aws_secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

In config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb I have added:

```
S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  aws_region: 'us-east-1'
)
```

but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

create an initializer with aws.rb with:(or add if you already have it)

```
S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  access_key_id: 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
  secret_access_key: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
  region: 'REGION'
)
```

Comment: See edit, I've added to the initializer but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this command locally, then the problem is that the ENV is not set on your local computer.

Heroku should auto precompile your assets as part of deployment.  If you have to do it on local machine just set the ENV variable.